# Linking master report and subreport when rewriting the subreport datasource

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a set of 'Master' tables (TableA, TableB, TableC) which can each optionally be linked (many to many) to a set of 'Linked' tables (TableX, TableY, TableZ) via junction tables (jctTableAX, jctTableAY, jctTableAZ etc.)

Each item in a table has a unique (Long) identifier (e.g. Aid, Xid) which are used to construct the links and a unique (string) Selector (e.g. ASelector, XSelector) that is displayed to the user.

Each master or linked table has an associated query (e.g. qryA, qryX) that pulls out all the table data and sorts it by Selector.

I want to produce a set of reports showing the full detail for each item from a 'Master' table (A/B/C); each report will have a set of three subreports showing lists of the linked selectors.

(In practice there are a dozen master tables, and a dozen linked tables, and some tables can be either master tables or linked tables depending on the context, so I need a generic scaleable solution -- the most subreports there will be in any report is 4 however, as not every combination of table links is supported.)

My current design has a report for each Master table, and a single subreport for each linked table. These subreports are included in each of the master reports, and the data source for the subreport is rewritten in the subrreport Open event thus (example is for subreport for linked items of type X)

```
     Dim strMasterType As String
     Dim strJunctionTable As String
     Static intCallCount As Long

     If intCallCount = 0 Then 'Only execute this once

         strMasterType = FormItemType(CurrentMasterForm) 'returns A B or C
         strJunctionTable = GetJunctionTable(strMasterType, "X") 'returns the relevant junction table name

         Me.RecordSource = "SELECT " & strJunctionTable & ".*,  qryX.*, " & strJunctionTable & "." & strMasterType & "id AS MasterID FROM " & strJunctionTable & " LEFT JOIN qryX ON " & strJunctionTable & ".Xid = qryX.Xid;"


     End If
     intCallCount = intCallCount + 1
```

Link Master Field is Aid. Link Child Field is MasterID (These are set at report design time, but I believe this should let me rewrite the subreport source for different master reports as long as the subreport source always has in it a MasterID field.)

1. Is this design sensible or is there a better approach to the problem?
2. There's something wrong either in the Link Master Field/Link Child Field set-up or the RecordSource SQL as I'm getting the same data in the subreports even though linked data differs between the master items, but I'm going code-blind trying to sort it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're describing sounds reasonable, though I'm not sure about the finer details. I'd recommend removing the setting of Link Master & Child in  design view; it might also be a good idea to remove the subreports themselves from the sub-report controls on the parent reports. If you did this, when the report opens, the main report's open event will fire (because no child-reports yet exist):

```
private sub report_open(cancel as integer)
    me.recordsource = ...
    me.childreport1.sourceobject = ... 'name of child report; 
        'this line will cause the open event of the sub report to fire; 
        'use that event to set the sub-report's record source by
        'if me.recordsource = "" then 
        '    me.recordsource = ... 
    me.childreport1.linkmasterfield = ... 'or whatever the property is called
    me.childreport1.linkchildfield = ...
end sub
```

This approach works happily in a form that displays different sub-forms in the same sub-form object depending on the user's selection in another control, so I would expect it to work for your application also.